# Find parent tag xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to get the parent node of a particular tag type .
For ex- Input XML is below-

```
<table type="SPECIALMATERIALtbl" UID="2001">
    <row class="FIGURE" type="SPECIALMATERIALrow">
      <cell class="FIGURE" colspan="7">
        This is a cell
      </cell>
    </row>
   </table>
```

So, I want to get the type attribute of 'table' element above when I am inside the cell template in XSLT. I want to do this only for parent element of type  - 'table' . So the output to above should be- "SPECIALMATERIALtbl"

Awaiting a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `<cell>` being the context node, `<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/@type"/>` returns what you want.